# Should I sear sous-vide chicken breasts?

Tags: chicken, sous-vide, chicken-breast

I'm planning on cooking some boneless skinless chicken breasts tonight sous-vide.  Should I finish them with a quick pan sear like I do with my steaks or should I just season and slice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would sear. It is not necessary, really, but I prefer the texture and flavor that comes with a good sear. To me, while it would be moist and tender, it would also be rather uninteresting. Bear in mind much of this is driven by personal preference.

Comment: I think I share these preferences too.  This was my intuition.  I imagine if I was using the chicken for a chicken salad or a sauced wrap the sear might become unnecessary.  Thanks!